# Postgres Where query not working with numeric value for character varying data types

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here I'm using postgres 9.6 And PFA is my table schema for postgres

```
id  username
----------
1   ashesh 
2   123456
```

While doing a query on a username with `'123456'` it will not gives the response but when doing a query with 'ashesh' it will give a response. My query is

```
select * from customer where username = '123456';
```

Gives me a blank response but while querying with 'ashesh'

```
select * from customer where username = 'ashesh';
```

it will give the response.

Comment: How can we reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Maybe some trailing spaces. Does `where username like '123456%'` work? Do you have an unique index on that column? What is your exact Postgres version (`select version()` will tell you).

Comment: You can also try [**SPLIT_TO_ARRAY**](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_string_to_array-function.php) to check the string for weird characters

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, sometimes you keep a blank in the username value(it seems for `123456`),

`trim` may be used in the where condition for *username* column :

```
create table customer( ID int, username varchar(125));
insert into customer values(1,'ashesh');
insert into customer values(2,'123456 ');

create table customer( ID int, username varchar(125));
insert into customer values(1,'ashesh');
id  username
1   ashesh

select * from customer where trim(username) = 'ashesh';
1   ashesh

select * from customer where username = '123456';
--no results return

select * from customer where trim(username) = '123456';
id  username
2   123456
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f8e95/3)

Comment: using trim is works, but why this type of issue is created, bcoz I had updated same value but gives no result. Any reason behind that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would seem to be hidden characters -- either in the `where` constant or in the column itself.  If the first, then simply re-typing the code should fix the problem.

The second requires more investigation.  I would start with:

```
where username like '%123456%'
```

to see if any usernames contain that sequence of characters.  If this finds the row, then start looking for hidden characters.  If not, then try:

```
where username like '%1%2%3%4%5%6%'
```

This will look for hidden characters between the digits.  Once you have determined what the issue is, you can figure out how to deal with the problem.

If you have a fixed set of characters that are allowed, you can also test:

```
where regexp_replace(username, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', 'g') = '123456'
```

If this is the problem, you can remove the hidden characters with:

```
update customer
    set username = regexp_replace(username, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', 'g')
    where username ~ '[^a-zA-Z0-9]';
```

Comment: this will work, but I want an exact match in the column value. This type of issue creates while the only numeric value is present in the row. otherwise, it will work fine.

Comment: @AsheshKhatri . . . You need to find the cause of the problem, if you want your queries to work.